# "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" Error in if statement in R

Tags: r, function, variables, local, variable-declaration

I am trying to count and print the cases in which the values in second and third columns of my dataframe named 'DATA'. 
But I have "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" Error.

Could you help me please? How can I write my condition in if statement without getting this error?

My Code:

```
deneme<-function(id=vector()){
i<-1
counter<-1
sulfate<-DATA[,2]
nitrate<-DATA[,3]
while (DATA[i,4] == DATA[i+1,4]){
if(DATA[i,2] != NA & DATA[i,3] != NA){
counter<-counter+1

}
i<-i+1
}

print(counter)  
}
```

Comment: Please provide some example dataset and expected result

Comment: ##   id nobs
## 1  1  117 is the output

Comment: Writing a line like `if(DATA[i,2] != NA & DATA[i,3] != NA)` means that you didn't grasp what a `NA` value is in R. Check `is.na` function and try what happens with `NA==NA`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when `DATA[i,2]` is `NA`, the comparison is also `NA`:

```
NA != NA
#[1] NA
```

You need to use function `is.na` to test wether you have `NA` value:

```
!is.na(NA)
#[1] FALSE
```

Hence, you should change your line of code to:

```
if(!is.na(DATA[i,2]) & !is.na(DATA[i,3]))
```