# Direct way of telling ifelse to ignore NA

Tags: r, if-statement, na

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28474750/4798582) when the test condition in `ifelse(test, yes, no)` is `NA`, the evaluation is also `NA`. Hence the following returns...

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA ,NA),
                 b = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA),
                 c = c(rep(NA, 4), 1, 1))
ifelse(df$a==1, "a==1", 
    ifelse(df$b==1, "b==1", 
        ifelse(df$c==1, "c==1", NA)))
#[1] "a==1" "a==1" NA     NA     NA     NA
```

... instead of the desired

```
#[1] "a==1" "a==1" "b==1" "b==1"  "c==1" "c==1"
```

As suggested by Cath, I can circumvent this problem by formally specifying that the test condition should not include NA:

```
ifelse(df$a==1 &  !is.na(df$a), "a==1", 
    ifelse(df$b==1 & !is.na(df$b), "b==1", 
        ifelse(df$c==1 & !is.na(df$c), "c==1", NA)))
```

However, as akrun also noted, this solution becomes rather lengthy with increasing number of columns.

---

A workaround would be to first replace all `NA`s with a value not present in the data.frame (e.g, 2 in this case):

```
df_noNA <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2 ,2),
                 b = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                 c = c(rep(2, 4), 1, 1))

ifelse(df_noNA$a==1, "a==1", 
    ifelse(df_noNA$b==1, "b==1", 
        ifelse(df_noNA$c==1, "c==1", NA)))
#[1] "a==1" "a==1" "b==1" "b==1"  "c==1" "c==1"
```

However, I was wondering if there was **a more direct way to tell `ifelse` to ignore NAs**? Or is writing a function for `& !is.na` the most direct way?

```
ignorena <- function(column) {
        column ==1 & !is.na(column)
}
ifelse(ignorena(df$a), "a==1", 
    ifelse(ignorena(df$b), "b==1", 
        ifelse(ignorena(df$c), "c==1", NA)))
#[1] "a==1" "a==1" "b==1" "b==1"  "c==1" "c==1"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `%in%` instead of `==` to sort-of ignore `NA`s.

```
ifelse(df$a %in% 1, "a==1", 
       ifelse(df$b %in% 1, "b==1", 
              ifelse(df$c %in% 1, "c==1", NA)))
```

Unfortunately, this does not give any performance gain compared to the original while @arkun's solution is about 3 times faster.

```
solution_original <- function(){
  ifelse(df$a==1 &  !is.na(df$a), "a==1", 
         ifelse(df$b==1 & !is.na(df$b), "b==1", 
                ifelse(df$c==1 & !is.na(df$c), "c==1", NA)))
}

solution_akrun <- function(){
  v1 <- names(df)[max.col(!is.na(df)) * NA^!rowSums(!is.na(df))]
  i1 <- !is.na(v1)
  v1[i1] <- paste0(v1[i1], "==1")
}

solution_mine <- function(x){
  ifelse(df$a %in% 1, "a==1", 
         ifelse(df$b %in% 1, "b==1", 
                ifelse(df$c %in% 1, "c==1", NA)))
}
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(c(1, rep(NA, 4)), 1e6, T),
                 b = sample(c(1, rep(NA, 4)), 1e6, T),
                 c = sample(c(1, rep(NA, 4)), 1e6, T))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  solution_original(),
  solution_akrun(),
  solution_mine()
)
## Unit: milliseconds
##                expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
## solution_original() 701.9413 839.3715 845.0720 853.1960 875.6151 1051.6659   100
##    solution_akrun() 217.4129 242.5113 293.2987 253.2144 387.1598  564.3981   100
##     solution_mine() 698.7628 845.0822 848.6717 858.7892 877.9676 1006.2872   100
```

Was inspired by this: [R: Dealing with TRUE, FALSE, NA and NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822426/r-dealing-with-true-false-na-and-nan)

**Edit**

Following the comment by @arkun, I redid the benchmark and revised the statement.

Comment: I was using the data with 6 rows supplied by the OP.

Comment: Did it. See the edit. Your solution is faster as it turned out. However, I also found that your solution does not return the collect output when all values in a row are `NA`s (the value in your solution is `c==3` which is not the OP wanted). I can rerun the benchmark if you provide a fix.

Comment: That is a simple fix in my part, but I think the OP's example doesn't show that kind of a pattern

Comment: Although %in% works in this case, I would not advise it generally as when you have `vector.a %in% vector.b` you will get NA when both vectors have NA - and that may not be what you want.

Answer (score 5):

`dplyr::case_when` is a convenient alternative to cascading `ifelse` calls:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA ,NA),
                 b = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA),
                 c = c(rep(NA, 4), 1, 1))

df %>% mutate(equals = case_when(a == 1 ~ 'a==1', 
                                 b == 1 ~ 'b==1', 
                                 c == 1 ~ 'c==1'))
#>    a  b  c equals
#> 1  1 NA NA   a==1
#> 2  1 NA NA   a==1
#> 3 NA  1 NA   b==1
#> 4 NA  1 NA   b==1
#> 5 NA NA  1   c==1
#> 6 NA NA  1   c==1
```

It cascades like `ifelse`, so if the first condition is true, the first result is returned even if the second and third conditions are true too. If none are true, it returns `NA`:

```r
set.seed(47)
df <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1, NA), 30, replace = TRUE), 10)), letters[1:3])

df %>% mutate(equals = case_when(a == 1 ~ 'a==1', 
                                 b == 1 ~ 'b==1', 
                                 c == 1 ~ 'c==1'))
#>     a  b  c equals
#> 1  NA  1  1   b==1
#> 2   1 NA NA   a==1
#> 3  NA  1 NA   b==1
#> 4  NA NA  1   c==1
#> 5  NA NA NA   <NA>
#> 6  NA NA  1   c==1
#> 7   1  1  1   a==1
#> 8   1  1  1   a==1
#> 9  NA  1 NA   b==1
#> 10 NA  1 NA   b==1
```

Plus it's fast:

```r
set.seed(47)
df <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1, NA), 3 * 1e5, replace = TRUE), ncol = 3)), letters[1:3])

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    original = {
        ifelse(df$a == 1 &  !is.na(df$a), "a==1", 
               ifelse(df$b == 1 & !is.na(df$b), "b==1", 
                      ifelse(df$c == 1 & !is.na(df$c), "c==1", NA)))},
    akrun = {
        v1 <- names(df)[max.col(!is.na(df)) * NA^!rowSums(!is.na(df))]
        i1 <- !is.na(v1)
        v1[i1] <- paste0(v1[i1], "==1")
    },
    amatsuo_net = {
        ifelse(df$a %in% 1, "a==1", 
               ifelse(df$b %in% 1, "b==1", 
                      ifelse(df$c %in% 1, "c==1", NA)))
    },
    alistaire = {
        df %>% mutate(equals = case_when(a == 1 ~ 'a==1', 
                                         b == 1 ~ 'b==1', 
                                         c == 1 ~ 'c==1'))
    }
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>         expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#>     original 81.19896 86.11843 110.93882 123.92463 128.58037 171.11026   100
#>        akrun 27.50351 30.99127  38.98353  32.67991  34.64947  77.98958   100
#>  amatsuo_net 83.75744 88.54095 109.22226 110.40066 129.02168 170.92911   100
#>    alistaire 16.57426 18.91951  21.73293  19.29925  24.30350  33.83180   100
```

Comment: I am not sure why your first chunk of code does not run any longer.

Comment: @B.Davis It still all works the same for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'a' not found`

Comment: with `dplyr_0.5.0` and `R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)` but I have not yet tried an update

Comment: @B.Davis When `case_when` was first introduced, it used base semantics instead of dplyr-style NSE, so you had to write `.$a`. It was fully integrated at some point, so with the current version either style will work.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this more efficiently without nested `ifelse` loops.  For the first dataset, we create a logical matrix (`!is.na(df)`) for non-NA elements, get the column index of the maximum value i.e. TRUE for each row, use that index to get the column names and `paste` with `==1`

```
paste0(names(df)[max.col(!is.na(df))], "==1")
#[1] "a==1" "a==1" "b==1" "b==1" "c==1" "c==1"
```

If there are rows with only NAs

```
v1 <- names(df)[max.col(!is.na(df)) * NA^!rowSums(!is.na(df))]
i1 <- !is.na(v1)
v1[i1] <- paste0(v1[i1], "==1")
```

and for the second dataset as there are no NAs, we can directly compare with 1 to get a logical matrix, do the same step as before

```
paste0(names(df_noNA)[max.col(df_noNA == 1)], "==1")
#[1] "a==1" "a==1" "b==1" "b==1" "c==1" "c==1"
```

Comment: does this mean that there is no direct way of telling `ifelse` to ignore NAs apart from specifying for every condition that `ifelse` should ignore NAs?

Comment: @Flo You need to `!is.na`

Comment: @akroun thanks for clarifying and +1 for efficient solution! I accepted amatsuo_net's answer because it provides "a more direct way to tell `ifelse` to ignore `NA`s".