# Create new variables with mutate (ifelse()), but get wrong answer because of NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new variable c. Step 1, if a=1 then c=1 (regardless of b); step 2, if a=2 or b=2, then c=2.

```
a <- c (2, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1)
b <- c (1, 2, NA, 1, 2, NA, 1, 2, NA)
ab <- data.frame (a, b)
abc <- ab %>% 
    mutate (c = ifelse (a == 1, 1, NA)) %>% 
    mutate (c = ifelse (a == 2 | b == 2, 2, c))

abc
   a  b  c
1  2  1  2
2  2  2  2
3  2 NA  2
4 NA  1 NA
5 NA  2  2
6 NA NA NA
7  1  1  1
8  1  2  2
9  1 NA NA
```

I expect c to be (2,2,2,NA,2,NA,1,2,1), but the actual out put is (2,2,2,NA,2,NA,1,2,NA). Why is the last cell changed to be NA (it should be 1)?

Comment: Try `ifelse(a ==1, 1, ifelse(a == 2 | b == 2, 2, NA))`. Also why *row: 8* becomes 2? The first condition is `a == 1`...? The last cell changes because in the second `ifelse` you do not have a condition for `a == 1`. It only checks for `a == 2` or `b == 2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Direct way of telling ifelse to ignore NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410704/direct-way-of-telling-ifelse-to-ignore-na)

Comment: The documentation for ifelse states that it will return `Where condition is TRUE, the matching value from true, where it's FALSE, the matching value from false, otherwise NA`. Since b ==2 in the second mutate evaluates to NA for last row thus the NA in result. However in case of comment by Sotos it will  never do this evaluation and thus not have an NA.

Comment: Then put the conditions the other way around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good place for `case_when`, which evaluates each case until it finds one that's `TRUE`. It sounds like the two conditions should be swapped if you want row 8 to be 2.

```
library(dplyr)
abc <- ab %>%
  mutate(c = case_when(a == 2 | b == 2 ~ 2,
                       a == 1          ~ 1,
                       TRUE            ~ NA_real_))

#> abc
#   a  b  c
#1  2  1  2
#2  2  2  2
#3  2 NA  2
#4 NA  1 NA
#5 NA  2  2
#6 NA NA NA
#7  1  1  1
#8  1  2  2
#9  1 NA  1
```

Comment: The answer is what I want but I still want to know,  why Row#8 turns out to be 1 when fitting the second condition? Many thanks.

Comment: In your original code, looking at row 8, the first condition would be `TRUE` and make c = 1. Then the 2nd condition also `TRUE`, so that'd override the prior assignment and make c = 2.  In the `case_when` statement here, it looks for the first TRUE and then stops.